# What is it called when picking the produce the farmers are not collecting?

Tags: vegetables, fruits, terminology

Recently I've found an association that collects the produce the farmers are not picking and gives it to charities. Many times, the farmers are not picking the fruits or vegetables they grow because it's not worth it. The market price is too low so the price of picking + transporting the produce is higher than the income they get from selling it. In some cases that's because the produce is simply not the first quality, in other cases that's because they were affected by diseases or bad weather (hail).

The association has a good relation with the farmers and then, when the farmers don't want the produce, they call this association to come and pick them. The association is collecting it using volunteers.

What's the name of such an activity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This activity is called "gleaning". A word you will find in the Bible.

For example, "And when ye reap the harvest of your land, thou shalt not make clean riddance of the corners of thy field when thou reapest, neither shalt thou gather any gleaning of thy harvest: thou shalt leave them unto the poor, and to the stranger: I am the Lord your God."  King James Version, Leviticus 23:22

Millet painted a picture of it titled, of course, "The Gleaners"
[image: The Gleaners]
courtesy Wikipedia